# Is or Was when talking about a historic figure in the present?

Tags: american-english

If I ask someone the question "Who is Martin Luther King Jr." is that correct compared to "Who was Martin Luther King Jr.?"

Which one is the correct sentence and how?

Comment: In my mind is draws attention to his present legacy, while was draws attention to his life in the 1950's and 60's.

Comment: Normally, for a person you know to be deceased, you would use "who was".  In fact, "who was" would also be appropriate for, say, a retired-but-still-living actor, since it is basically asking "What was the significance of this person, in his time?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I say "Neil Armstrong is the first man to walk on the Moon"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/537938/can-i-say-neil-armstrong-is-the-first-man-to-walk-on-the-moon)

Comment: Good question. Although I might very well ask a question like "Who is Martin Luther King, Jr?" as a way of inviting an appraisal of his, life, legacy, and significance, I would be very unlikely to ask " What is the Roman Empire?" even if I were interested in similar things about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not know that Martin Luther King Jr. is deceased, you can ask "Who is Martin Luther King Jr.?"

If you have figured out that he is dead, and you want to know more about Martin Luther King Jr. as a person, you can ask "Who was Martin Luther King Jr.?" This can get you the facts about his life and possibly a lot of information on his legacy (hearer's choice).

If you want to refer to his person (the man) as a symbol of "what that he means", you can say "Who is Martin Luther King Jr.?" or "Who is Martin Luther King Jr. today" or "Who is Martin Luther King Jr. for us?" or...

Answer (score 2):

I am grammatically untutored, so my response is directed only at the *propriety* of asking who a deceased person--in this case, one of great public acclaim--**is**, rather than asking who that person, **was**. I would answer that, though Martin Luther King Jr. is deceased his legacy lives and endures. In the case of a personage such as Dr. King, I don't believe that you can *productively* separate this man from his legacy, so I feel it would be completely acceptable--that is, *not improper*--to ask, **"Who is Dr. Martin Luther King Jr.?"** Grammarians may respond differently.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct.

In legal writing, we regularly discuss past issues--sometimes discussing events in cases from hundreds of years ago. There are two things that matter: subject-verb agreement within the sentence, and consistent "voice" within the document.

In your example, in colloquial speech, both forms are acceptable. If you are giving an oral presentation or writing a document, use either form as long as it matches the tense ("voice") of your other sentences.

Caveat: there are situations when you will want to break this rule. For example, you might tell a story about John Doe and you might have John Doe speak about MLK in a different tense ("voice") than you are using in the rest of the document. This is acceptable and sometimes useful.

Comment: +1 @Hunter Hogan - good answer that simplifies and makes clear what's important.

Comment: @LittleEva Commenting on a user's answer will automatically notify them of the comment; no need to ping them with an @ symbol, FYI.

Comment: +1 @TylerH - Right. Right. Thanks for reminding me brother.