# Can I say "Neil Armstrong is the first man to walk on the Moon"?

Tags: tenses

I saw this sentence in my textbook.

> Neil Armstrong was the first man to walk on the Moon.

I have a question. Can't I use simple present tense

> “Neil Armstrong is the first man to walk on the Moon”

to talk about a fact?

Comment: Well, he isn't walking on the Moon now. That was 51 years ago.

Comment: And he isn't walking anywhere right now, since he's dead.

Comment: N.A. died in 2012. We don't talk about the deceased as if they are still living.

Comment: Related: [What does '**are** organized' mean in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190104/what-does-are-organized-mean-in-this-sentence/190105#190105)

Answer (score 1):

Using the present simple to talk about an event that took place in the past is called the narrative present, the historic/al present, or the dramatic present usage. See for example [ThoughtCo_Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/historical-present-verb-tense-1690928). It is used to add tension to stories, drawing the audience in:

- (The door was ajar.

Matt Barratt draws his gun, aims at the figure standing on the chair, and shoots Bobby the Kid in his back.)

and in giving historical data, especially when listing events:

> ... ... ...
>
> - 19 July.   1545    King Henry VIII looks on as his newly refitted flagship the Mary Rose sinks in the Solent, off England’s south coast,
>   with the loss of 700 lives.
> - 20 July.   1588    The Spanish Armada consisting of 130 warships set sail for England from Corunna, a day later than expected due to a
>   storm.
> - 21 July.   1969    The Eagle lands on the moon and US astronaut Neil Armstrong is the first man in history to walk on its powdery surface.
> - 22 July.   1946    More than a year after the end of World War Two, bread is rationed in Britain. The shortage is blamed upon a poor
>   harvest and drought.
> - 23 July.   1940    The Local Defence Volunteers changes its name to the Home Guard. The one million-strong force, which includes many World
>   War One veterans, is intended to form Britain’s last line of defence
>   against the expected German invasion.
> - 24 July.   1567    Mary Queen of Scots abdicates after defeat by the Protestants at Carberry Hill, near Musselburgh, East Lothian....

[[Historic UK: Historic July](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofBritain/Historic-July/)] (note the inconsistency)

So, such a usage is certainly licensed. But as always, context is highly important. It would sound distinctly odd to choose the dramatic/historical present rather than past simple to state a past event in most contexts (including conversation and normal prose).

Comment: But you can say Neil Armstrong is the first man *to have walked* on the moon.

Comment: Yes, that's a more normal-sounding (conversationally) variant. Standalone, it hints that he's still alive, though. It's in a more formal register than the past simple phrasing.